# Downgrade from iOS 11 (beta) to iOS 10.3.2 and restore iOS 11 backup

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, beta-seed-program

I've upgraded my iPhone to iOS 11, but I regretted from doing this. I've a backup saved at iCloud from Yesterday, and I would like to know if I reset my phone back to iOS 10.3 it's ok to restore this backup, even if it was made at iOS 11. There is something that I have to take careful or something that I will lose during the process?

Im okay about having to download all the apps again, I just dont want to lose the phone data (WhatsApp chats, Contacts, Photos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restore a backup from a newer iOS version to an older iOS version.

You should have an iTunes backup from before you updated iOS. If not, you will have to manually extract the data from your iOS 11 backup and add it back to your device after setting up your iPhone as new with iOS 10.3. How you do this depends on the individual app — many use iCloud such as iCloud backup in WhatsApp which will help you do this automatically, but otherwise it will be a case of manually editing a fresh backup of your iOS 10.3 device with an app such as [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm). For things which are incompatible with older iOS such as your messages history, this will be unable to be restored to the older iOS.

Unfortunately all I can say is that you are warned of the perils of installing beta iOS prior to acceptance of the beta program. My suggestion is to put up with iOS 11 and keep updating to the latest beta as it becomes available, which will fix many of the bugs. You'll be updating to iOS 11 anyway in the future.

Comment: But why do items saved in iCloud are attached to the device system? Because such files as photos, documents, messages are well synced between my iPhone and my Mac, why do, example, WhatsApp chats, are attached to the device?

Answer (score 1):

If you have data from WhatsApp, Phone, etc... that you want to keep, there is no reliable way to get it onto iOS 10 from iOS 11 backup.  iCloud will have whatever is on there and that data is available to iOS 10 or iOS 11 but not everything is on iCloud.

The best solution is to just stick with iOS 11 and get updates as they come.

N.B. - Every Apple hacker makes this mistake at some point so embrace it!  Apple OS betas are really rough around the edges.  Bugs & battery life issues abound.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to focus on the “you can’t restore a newer backup on older iOS” part of [this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/286350/5472).

You will not be able to get back text messages, sync with apple music, and many more. Upgrading to the beta will mean rolling back to 10.3.2 will ruin any icloud functionality except photos and contacts

Comment: But he started the answer with: "You can't restore a backup from a newer iOS version to an older iOS version.".

Comment: I’ve linked to the other answer - first can mean Time, votes or most recently edited