# How to downgrade iOS 11 beta to iOS 10 without PC?

Tags: ios, downgrade

I have iPad and I recently installed iOS 11 beta 1 on my iPad. Now I see some battery issues and I want to downgrade to iOS 10.3.2. But I checked on the internet and shows that a PC is compulsory. **I don’t have a PC**.

Comment: Also keep in mind the data from iOS 11 won’t restore - you’ll need to sync or use an older backup for restore point. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286346/downgrade-from-ios-11-beta-to-ios-10-3-2-and-restore-ios-11-backup

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible without a PC or a Mac to initiate the wipe and also host the reinstall image download and USB control during the downgrade.

In addition to the "computer" - you need an Apple tool like iTunes (Mac or PC) or [Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) or [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator) (or a third party one like [Ground Control](https://www.groundctl.com)) to reload the older OS, since there is no OTA bundle for downgrading.

Comment: Well a Mac can be used - so no need of a PC :) - and yes iTunes is a must.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the substantial edit! I didn't know Xcode can install iOS versions, I can't seem to find a reference to this online? Also I think you didn't finish that last sentence

Comment: Yes. The last bit was about to repeat the first paragraph. Xcode relies on the same underlying framework as iTunes - I should double check this with iOS 11. The OTA profiles are so convenient I use that almost exclusively now and rarely manage updates tethered.

Comment: OTA profiles work when going UP in versions, but I am pretty sure they don't work when going DOWN a version. Especially when Apple themselves say that you can not downgrade from a beta (although the veracity of this is questionable)

Answer (score 0):

Need a computer. You can download ipsw file on PC or Mac from https://ipsw.me, and restore iPhone with the ipsw firmware by using iTunes. Or use system recovery tools to install ipsw without iTunes.

By the way, iOS 11 beta is only for the developer, not ready for common users now. iOS 11 beta is less buggy but still has many problems. Be patient and wait.

Answer (score 0):

By now Apple already stopped signing iOS 10, so it's impossible for you to downgrade iPad from iOS 11 to iOS 10.

Answer (score -2):

*POSSIBLE!*

Actually it is possible to downgrade from iOS 11 to iOS 10 without computer!

Firstly, you need to get the apple configuration profile I think it’s called that? But you need to download the iOS 10 version of it and reboot your iPad and then you’ll to software update and see that iOS 10 is there to be updated and then you will be downgraded!

Answer (score -3):

you can use reiboot downgrade ios 11 to ios 10 on Mac.
ReiBoot Mac verison 
http://download.cnet.com/Tenorshare-ReiBoot/3000-18546_4-76033925.html

Comment: This requires a computer, which the OP does not have