# Can I downgrade from iOS 11 developer beta? I'm not worried about data preservation

Tags: ios, downgrade, beta

**I simply want to get rid of this buggy beta.**

I regretfully installed the beta on my dailydrive/main device.

I'm aware that I may not be able to preserve all of my data because I didn't make any backups whatsoever, therefore I've performed manual backups of my most precious files.

I just want to go from iOS 11 Beta 2 to a clean and completely-reset latest-version of iOS 10.

I have the developer beta if that makes a difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone 7 Plus stuck in recovery mode and can't restore/update even in DFU after downgrading from iOS 11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/287747/iphone-7-plus-stuck-in-recovery-mode-and-cant-restore-update-even-in-dfu-after) with additional info at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286346/downgrade-from-ios-11-beta-to-ios-10-3-2-and-restore-ios-11-backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can always downgrade from iOS developer beta to stable version signed by Apple. Just follow these steps and you are good to go!

- First of all make sure you have latest version of iTunes if not
  update your iTunes to latest version.
- Then you have to download stable iOS file for your device. Use this [website](https://ipsw.me/) to download appropriate version (10.3.2) for your device.
- Turn of find my iPhone feature by going to **Settings** on your phone.
- Connect your device to computer and put your device in recovery mode. If you don't know how to put your device in recovery mode just google it or search it on youtube you will find tons of videos.
- Once your device is in recovery mode iTunes will pop up letting you know your device is in recovery mode. Press and hold the **OPTION** key if you are using Mac or **SHIFT** key on Windows and click on **Restore iPhone** .Browse the firmware you downloaded.
- Now sit back and relax your phone will be restored to iOS 10.3.2

Comment: Thank you so much.  I did this last year but have since completely forgotten how.  You jogged my memory and this sounds about right, so I went ahead and accepted this answer before doing it as I can't do it right away.  Thank you, again!

Comment: I would be wary of immediately accepting an answer without testing it - especially in this case as one of the linked answers specifically says this is not possible in one step.

Comment: I just said I've used this method before, it had just completely slipped my mind.  Therefore, I knew it would work.  I just finished and it worked, as I, from experience, *knew* it would.  Try it for yourself?

Comment: I do appreciate the point you're making, though.  No matter how "sure" I was I shouldn't accept an answer w/out verifying its effectiveness.  I'll take your concern under advisement in the future.  Good thing it actually worked this time, though, right? ;)

Comment: Guys I downgraded my own device following the same method before posting an answer here. So its completely safe to follow these steps. Peace :)